# auto-generate fields in inline admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have these (simplified) models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

class Invitation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

The `path` field in the `Invitation` table will contain a SHA1 hash that is going to be used as part of the URL to access the user's data.

I have this admin code:

```
class InvitationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Invitation

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (InvitationInline,)

admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

this displays the user and adds a list of invitations at the bottom.

Since my `path` values in the `Invitation` table are going to be generated by SHA1 algorithm from the user's email and the current timestamp, I need to:

1. have no empty 'Invitations' rows displayed by default in the `User` admin
2. remove the edit field for `path` column from the admin, and have the `path` field automatically generated when the "add another invitation" button is clicked.

I have no idea how to achieve this, could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To disable display of extra inline invitation forms [just add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra) `extra = 0` attribute to your `InvitationInline` class:

   ```
   class InvitationInline(admin.TabularInline):
       fields = ('user',)
       extra = 0
       model = models.Invitation
   ```
2. Probably, the best place to put the path generation is the [save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) of `Invitation` model:

   ```
   import hashlib
   import random

   class Invitation(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       path = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if self.pk is None:  # This is true only when the model has
                                # never been saved to database.
               salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
               self.path = hashlib.sha1(salt +\
                   str(self.user.email)).hexdigest()

           super(Invitation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

To remove `path` from `InvitationInline` just add [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) attribute to it: `fields = ('user',)`.